# Ubuntu 17.10 login page

Tags: login-screen, 17.10

I have updated my Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10,

but after login it will lock,

I have reinstalled gdm3 and lightdm but it won't fix.

finally I have install lxdm and it logged in but Unity’s Left Launcher doesn't appear,

what should I do restore my Ubuntu?